# Toolbar "Option" sign

Tags: 3d-view, eevee-render-engine, selection-tools, 3d-cursor, workspaces

Basically I'm using blender 2.8 as my current animation software. I was watching a tutorial, but I noticed that the "option" sign in the toolbar is not showing. How can I fix this? Is there another alternative to this? thank you.

Comment: Hi. Which 'option sign' are you referring to? Can you add a picture to show what you mean? Thanks.

Comment: adding a link to _"a tutorial"_ could narrow it down somewhat too. (and improve question 1000%)   Please don't keep asking same question.  Your new question also lacks detail. ,Please  [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/160978/15543) this question with some detail to clarify, and in all likelyhood it will be re-opened.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand your question. But if I understand correctly, click here.

[image]

Comment: See that "options" with the arrow pointing downwards at the right side of the toolbar? that one

Comment: @M4GN3TIC_ Daniele is right, you need to enable *Tool settings* panel through *View > Tool settings*.

Comment: none of those work, should I get blender 2.81?

Comment: @M4GN3TIC_ Oh, definitely. These options are only available since Blender 2.81. Or you can try the new 2.83 :)